# Asterisks render as question marks in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to join the Church of Emacs and I installed it because I wanted to use the org-mode.

I am using the Doom Emacs distribution.

The problem I am facing is that when I put `*` and press space I see a `?` rather than a nice bullet. (See the image).

What is wrong?

EDIT: Cross posted [here at github](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/3045).

[image]

Comment: IMO you'll receive quickly reply by [opening an issue to doom emacs repo](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/new/choose). People who don't use doom emacs have no idea how your configuration looks like.

Comment: @FirminMartin Thanks. I have posted it at git and edited to highlight the cross-posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wild guess would be that the customization that Doom does replaces the `*` with some fancy symbol, but that the font you are using is unable to display that symbol.  You could try switching the font or trying to find out which font Doom expects.